# Facebook authentication in php with graph api and sdk

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

i make Facebook authentication in my PHP website when I try to log in from my account it logins and when I try from any other account it shows the login feature currently unavailable for this app,

I have tried to log in by Sdk graph and do by 2 or 3 ways by seeing youtube videos but all time the same problem only I can log in with Facebook with the account on which the app was made and I also do ap live but not work

Comment: _"and I also do ap live but not work"_ - meaning what, exactly? That you could _not_ successfully set it live? That is a requirement for other users, that do not have a role in your app, to be able to login.

Comment: mean when we made facebook app for authentication there is two modes developer and live so i do live there, here is my web https://afrahbladi.com/login.php

Comment: The actual message I am getting says, _"Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app."_ - sounds to me as if you still have parts of it in review ...?

Comment: yes same message every time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am new here tell me how i can send all the files code here